# How to use tweed_mode= extended in twitter rest api request?

Tags: php, json, api, twitter

I Am building a php app and an sending the following request

```
$data= $mycon->get("/statuses/show/".$id);
```

the above request works fine for tweets which are upto 140 characters and return media objects
extended entities if it has any attached to it .
for more than 140 characters am doing the following request

```
$data= $mycon->get("/statuses/show/".$id."&tweet_mode=extended")
```

but  its  saying page does not exist and  if  i go with the below Call

```
$data= $mycon->get("/statuses/show/".$id."?tweet_mode=extended")
```

then its say could not authenticate you

Comment: it doesn't support with `/statuses/show/`[https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/get-statuses-show-id]

Answer (score 0):

```
// How should external links be opened?
function get_target()
{
// Kindle doesn't support opening in a new window
if (stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "Kindle/"))
{
    return "_self";
}
else
{
    return "_blank";
}
  }
```

Source - https://github.com/edent/Dabr/blob/master/i/common/twitter.php

Comment: sorry ididnt get you .  actually  for now  i want to just json data back .  tweets with 140 characters returns all the  attached media but   tweets more than 140 doesnt return anything